# Upgrade Win7 Home to Ultimate - will dual-boot with Ubuntu still work? / Partition access question

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, windows-7

1. I had *Windows 7 Home Basic* installed.Then I install Ubuntu and know I have dual boot. But I want to upgrade my *Windows 7* to *Ultimate* version.Can I update my *Windows 7* installation and keep my dual boot setup as well as my files from the old *Windows 7 Home Basic*?
2. From the *Windows 7* installation, I can't access the Ubuntu partition, but from Ubuntu I can access the Windows 7 partition. If I get a virus on windows 7 which destroys my files, Ubuntu will still be safe there in dual boot, right?

Comment: You should split your questions up into 2 different posts. At least for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know what the Upgrade will do with the Windows files, but I am quite sure that it will restore the boot loader to Microsoft, so your GRUB boot menu will be gone and the machine would boot straight into Windows, I suppose. But this can be fixed: Follow this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/367990) (maybe print it out) after the Upgrade, to restore the GRUB and fix the dual-boot. The Upgrade should not touch your Ubuntu partition, so it should be fine after that.
2. The Windows system can not access your Ubuntu partition, because it is formatted in ext4, which is unsupported by Windows without special drivers. And as applications use system calls to access the drives (normally), they can't access Ubuntu's files either, as long as they don't install their own driver (99.99999% will definitely not!) The only thing Windows (applications) can do to harm Ubuntu's files is to completely delete or reformat the partition. It is possible, but very unlikely, because viruses that are so aggressive are not very widespread. So you are pretty safe, but totally safe is only an external hdd you physically disconnect.

Comment: I will do as you said tomorow